# Unexpected number of splitViewControllers when targeting an iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm learning to use the split view in an app. I am asking the table to reload the data every time I add new things. My code and settings are seem fine. But not work on iPhone. After I ask someone and he told me to try on an iPad device, it works.

Finally, I find out where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. I added a line that prints the size of `splitView.viewControllers`. The iPad simulator returns 2, which is what I am expecting. But it returns 1 without any changes in the iPhone device. So, what's wrong with it, and how may I solve it? Thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hi26.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQERA.png)

Comment: That is the expected and correct behavior. Split view controllers are adaptive. On an iPhone they turn into an ordinary navigation controller.

Comment: @matt I embedded the views into navigations, it should work, that's what my tutorial says. Or how can I make it run in the iPhone simulator?

Comment: The point is, “it returns 1 without any changes in the iPhone device” is correct and there’s no problem.

Comment: So, do I have a way to get the master view from the detail view in iPhone mode?

Comment: There’s a lot of configuration you have to do, as in this example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS13bookExamples/bk2ch09p488basicMasterDetail/MasterDetail/AppDelegate.swift